# Is there a way to call a method of a class object thread and have it run in that specific thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, dictionary, oop, python-multithreading

**Context:**

I have a threading class, which is called 10 times in a for loop.

For each object of the class, I pass in a `username` for the user which is determined by its place in the for loop, e.g `user0, user1, user2` ect.

I created a method called `new_message()` in the class, which just prints another message.

In the `def run()` method of the class, I added the `username` as key and the `new_message()` function as the value into a dictionary

**My Problem:**

I tried to call the `new_message()` function for one of the users, and that hopelfully the function would run in thread created for that specific user, but instead I think it ran in the main thread, causing my next lines of code to wait.

**So my question is:**

Is there a way to call a method of a class object thread and have it run in that specific thread?

---

Do note this is representation of a larger problem I have, but I have made a minimal reproduced example which mimics my code.

**Code:**

```
import time

import threading

dict = {

}

class go(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, username):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.username = username

    def run(self):
        dict[self.username] = self.new_message
        for count in range(10):
            print('Hello: '+self.username+'\n')
            time.sleep(10)

    def new_message(self):
        for count in range(10):
            print('How are you: '+self.username)
            time.sleep(2)


for count in range(10):
    username = ('user' + str(count))
    go(username).start()


what_user = input('What user')
dict[what_user]()

Print('This line shouldn't be waiting to print')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to call a method of a class object thread and have it run in that specific thread?

No this is not possible. You have already `start()`ed the thread, which makes it run its `run()` method. You cannot call a method like that to run it in that specific thread -- it'll simply run on the thread that called it as you observed (it ran in your main thread).

You need the other threads (let's call them worker threads) to be **cooperative to externally submitted tasks** to make this happen. For instance, you may make the worker threads listen to a work queue after doing the initial work, to pick up tasks (i.e. functions) and run them.

Here is a quick implementation on your code:

```
import time

import threading
from queue import Queue

dict = {}


class Go(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, username, work_queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.username = username
        self.work_queue = work_queue

    def run(self):
        self.initialize()
        while True:
            task = self.work_queue.get()
            task()
            self.work_queue.task_done()

    def initialize(self):
        dict[self.username] = {"func": self.new_message, "queue": self.work_queue}
        for _ in range(10):
            print("Hello: " + self.username + "\n")
            time.sleep(10)

    def new_message(self):
        for _ in range(10):
            print("How are you: " + self.username)
            time.sleep(2)


for count in range(10):
    username = "user" + str(count)
    Go(username, Queue()).start()


what_user = input("What user")
selection = dict[what_user]
queue, method = selection["queue"], selection["func"]
queue.put(method)

print("This line shouldn't be waiting to print")
```

You'll observe that the `"This line shouldn't be waiting to print"` indeed won't wait now. Main thread puts it as a task on the queue for the chosen worker thread. The worker picks that up once it's done with its `self.initialize()` call.

Comment: This worked amazingly, I'm just confused how the while loop was able to run, when ```self.initialize``` hadn't finished running

Comment: It didn't run before -- it ran after `self.initialize`. In the meantime, the other "task" simply waits in the queue. The target thread picks it up once it's done with `self.initialize()`. If you want it to stop what it's doing, you'd need to add some conditional logic to break that initial while loop.

Comment: I'm very confused, I understand that ```self.initialize``` runs first, but the while loop, I don't understand how its executing or even being called, especially since ```self.initialize``` takes a while to finish

Comment: `self.initialize` runs for 100 seconds in worker threads (_not_ main thread). Sometime during this duration, you choose the user; at this point the main thread puts a task into the target queue. The worker thread, after 100 seconds, looks at the queue and sees a tasks waiting there for it. It picks it up and runs it (i.e. runs `new_message` function).

Comment: I see I now understand, so there isn't a way for ```def new_message(self)``` to run straight away aswell

Comment: Not on that specific thread, no. A thread can only run one thing at once.